# Perform Mail Merge And Not Show Word

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013, word-2013

I am performing a mail merge from Excel, which works exactly as I need.  My issue is that I am wanting to keep word hidden from the user, and that is not occurring.  I end up with an empty instance of word on the screen that I do not want.

This is my syntax - why am I unable to completely hide and close word when the process is finished?

```
    Dim wdapp As Word.Application, wdDoc As Word.Document, wdMaiMerge As Word.MailMerge
'Setting refs
Set wdapp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set wdDoc = wdapp.Documents.Open(wdpath)
Set wdMailMerge = wdDoc.MailMerge
'hiding display from user
wdapp.Visible = False
'Setting mail merge
With wdMailMerge
 .OpenDataSourcexxxx, ReadOnly:=False, LinkToSource:=True, AddToRecentFiles:=False
 .Execute
End With
'Finishing
Set wdapp = Nothing
wdapp.Quit
```

Comment: You should quit the app (`wdapp.Quit`) before releasing your reference to it (`Set wdapp = Nothing`).

Comment: @destination-data - still leaves me with blank word window.  And has word visible to user

Comment: Does your code contain any error handling?  What is the value of `wdapp.Visible` after this line `wdapp.Visible = False`?

Comment: @destination-data - no error handling...still trying to work out the bugs.  If I do a debug.print wdapp.Visible directly after that line it prints false

Comment: probably not making a difference with your problem, but you are using early and late binding combined .... Change `CreateObject("Word.Application")` to `New Word.Application`

Comment: @ScottHoltzman - thanks for the tip.  But like you said, does not make a difference with the issue posted.

Comment: go to Task Manager and ensure all versions of Word are terminated, then run again and see what happens. It may be an old instance left hanging

Comment: Have run the code with the task manager open?  Is it possible the code is opening, and closing, a second hidden instance of Word?  I made that mistake before.  Wasted more time than I'd like to admit searching for the solution.  FYI, [setting object vars to nothing is, generally, unnecessary](https://windowssecrets.com/forums/showthread.php/74789-Set-Variable-to-Nothing-(VBA-for-Excel)) (despite the fact this practice is widespread amongst VBA devs).

Comment: @ScottHoltzman - when I begin the process Task Manager shows no instances of WinWord.exe - however when it finishes one instance is remaining in Task Manager

Comment: @destination-data - from start to finish Task Manager only shows one instance of WinWord.exe

Comment: OK new approach.  Can you convert this to a [minimal, complete, verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?  Removing the code that isn't related to this question, line by line if you want, is a great way of identifying the problem.  If at the end of this exercise the bug is still there post the MCVE.  We can then try the code on our machines (I can't run your snippet, without first creating a mail merge etc).

Comment: @destination-data -> I am performing the mail merge in excel to word with data from a secondary excel workbook. I obviously can not provide an excel workbook, sod you just need the full VBA procedure I am using?

Comment: It's more about the exercise of removing code that isn't related to the problem.  It's amazing how many times this approach helps you to find the source of the problem.  Start with a full copy of the VBA.  Then start removing lines that shouldn't affect the visibility of Word.  Keep rerunning.  Sooner or later you'll narrow it down.

Comment: to @destination-data point, remove the part will it actually does the mail merge and see if you are left with a hanging instance of Word. Also, add `wdDoc.Close False` before `wdApp.Quit` see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You're not telling Word what query to use or what to do with either the document you're using for the mailmerge once you've used it or the mailmerge output! And, if the document you're opening is a mailmerge main document, your code will hang at that point - you need to suppress that and supply all the SQL code yourself. For example:

```
Sub MailMerge()
'Note: A VBA Reference to the Word Object Model is required, via Tools|References
Dim wdApp As New Word.Application, wdDoc As Word.Document
Dim strWorkbookName As String: strWorkbookName = ThisWorkbook.FullName
With wdApp
  .Visible = False
  'Disable alerts to prevent an SQL prompt
  .DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone
  'Open the mailmerge main document
  Set wdDoc = .Documents.Open(Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\MailMergeMainDocument.docx", _
    ConfirmConversions:=False, ReadOnly:=True, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=False)
  With wdDoc
    With .MailMerge
      'Define the mailmerge type
      .MainDocumentType = wdFormLetters
      'Define the output
      .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
      .SuppressBlankLines = True
      'Connect to the data source
      .OpenDataSource Name:=strWorkbookName, ReadOnly:=True, _
        LinkToSource:=False, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto, _
        Connection:="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
        "User ID=Admin;Data Source=strWorkbookName;" & _
        "Mode=Read;Extended Properties=""HDR=YES;IMEX=1"";", _
        SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM `Sheet1$`", SubType:=wdMergeSubTypeAccess
      With .DataSource
        .FirstRecord = wdDefaultFirstRecord
        .LastRecord = wdDefaultLastRecord
      End With
      'Excecute the merge
      .Execute
      With wdApp.ActiveDocument
        'What do you want to do with the output document??? For example:
        .SaveAs2 Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\MailMergeOutputDocument.docx", _
          FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument, AddToRecentFiles:=False
        ' and/or:
        .SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\MailMergeOutputDocument.pdf", _
          FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF, AddToRecentFiles:=False
        'Close the output document
        .Close False
      End With
      'Disconnect from the data source
      .MainDocumentType = wdNotAMergeDocument
    End With
    'Close the mailmerge main document
    .Close False
  End With
  'Restore the Word alerts
  .DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsAll
  'Quit Word
  .Quit
End With
End Sub
```